# how to modify the anaconda environment prompt in zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh, prompt, datascience-anaconda

To make my command line prompt look prettier on zsh, I added this line to `.zshrc`:

```
PROMPT='%F{green}%n%f %B%F{blue}%1~%f%b $ '
```

However, when I activate an anaconda virtual environment (i.e. `conda activate base`), I see the name of the virtual environment on the left like this:

```
(base) myusername ~ $
```

I wonder how I can modify the virtual environment part of the prompt (say we want to color it to cyan for example)

Comment: hint: oh-my-zsh does all this for you :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for the suggestion! I think I am looking for a way to do that without installing oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 9):

The first step is to disable the default conda prompt modifier by running `conda config --set changeps1 false` as they already mentioned.

Next, add the following to your `.zshrc`:

```
# Determines prompt modifier if and when a conda environment is active
precmd_conda_info() {
  if [[ -n $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV ]]; then
    CONDA_ENV="($CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV) "
  # When no conda environment is active, don't show anything
  else
    CONDA_ENV=""
  fi
}

# Run the previously defined function before each prompt
precmd_functions+=( precmd_conda_info )

# Allow substitutions and expansions in the prompt
setopt prompt_subst

PROMPT='%F{cyan}$CONDA_ENV%f%F{green}%n%f %B%F{blue}%1~%f%b $ '
```

With this, the conda environment is shown before the rest of the prompt, inside parentheses, and in cyan.

If you want it to appear bold, enclose that portion in %B and %b:

```
PROMPT='%B%F{cyan}$CONDA_ENV%b%f%F{green}%n%f %B%F{blue}%1~%f%b $ '
```

If you want to use more colours, check whether your terminal supports it by running `echo $TERM`. If it returns `xterm-256color`, you can replace the colours in curly brackets by values from 0 to 255. You can check out the colours [here](https://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html).

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine.

Comment: Conda now defines `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`, which you can use directly.

Comment: @TheBamf Thats just for default env, we have to show the current activated env name

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
conda config --set changeps1 False
```

or add `changeps1: False` to your `.condarc`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it helps me with removing the virtual environment name. Do you also know how to modify the prompt? (i.e change the color, or make it bold)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 
[allerpi's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680112/532193) fails when switching conda environments.

This could be solved with a minor change:

1. Still, `conda config --set changeps1 false`
2. Append this snippet to your `~/.zshrc`

   ```bash
   # ~/.zshrc
   precmd_get_conda_env_name() {
   if [[ -n $CONDA_PREFIX ]]; then
       if [[ $(basename $CONDA_PREFIX) == "miniconda3" ]]; then
           CONDA_ENV="base"
       else
           CONDA_ENV="$(basename $CONDA_PREFIX)"
       fi
   else
       CONDA_ENV=""
   fi
   }
   precmd_functions+=( precmd_get_conda_env_name )
   precmd_update_prompt() {
       PROMPT=$'\n'"%B%F{black}[%F{green}%D{%m/%d %H:%M}%F{black}] %F{red}%n%F{black}@%F{yellow}%m%F{black}:%F{cyan}%~"$'\n'"%F{magenta}($CONDA_ENV)%F{blue} ➜ %f%b"
   }
   precmd_functions+=( precmd_update_prompt )
   ```

It would eventually look like:

- *iTerm2*

  [image: MacOS, iTerm2]
- *VSCode Integrated Terminal*

  [image: VSCode Integrated Terminal]